# Android: Beginner Adapter Trouble. How to solve setAdapter causing NullPointerException

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I got the following error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.ListActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(android.widget.ListAdapter)' on a null object reference
```

I am stuck and hope you can help.

`ThingsDB` is a list of `Thing(String what, String where)`

ListFragment:

```
import ... 

public class ListFragment extends Fragment{
    private static ThingsDB thingsDB;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        thingsDB = thingsDB.get(this.getActivity());
        ListView listView= (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.thing_list_view);
        ArrayAdapter<Thing> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Thing>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.text1, thingsDB.getThingsDB());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        return v;
    }
}
```

xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/fragment_list"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="@color/darkGrey"
              android:orientation="vertical">
   <ListView
        android:id="@+id/thing_list_view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="12dp">
    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling getview when the view is still not inflated, check the fragment lifecycle,`onCreate()` is called before `onCreateView()`
[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater, android.view.ViewGroup, android.os.Bundle)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Fragment.html#onCreateView(android.view.LayoutInflater,%20android.view.ViewGroup,%20android.os.Bundle))

> onCreate:
>   Added in API level 11 void onCreate (Bundle
>   savedInstanceState) Called to do initial creation of a fragment. This
>   is called after onAttach(Activity) and before
>   onCreateView(LayoutInflater, ViewGroup, Bundle), but is not called if
>   the fragment instance is retained across Activity re-creation (see
>   setRetainInstance(boolean)).
>
> onCreateView Called to have the fragment instantiate its user
>   interface view. This is optional, and non-graphical fragments can
>   return null (which is the default implementation). This will be called
>   between onCreate(Bundle) and onActivityCreated(Bundle).

In which case you will have

```
import ... 

public class ListFragment extends Fragment{
    private static ThingsDB thingsDB;
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        thingsDB = thingsDB.get(this.getActivity());
    }
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstance) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list, container, false);
        ListView listView= (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.thing_list_view);
        ArrayAdapter<Thing> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Thing>(this.getActivity(), R.layout.list_item, R.id.text1, thingsDB.getThingsDB());
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        return v;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! & appreciate the link as well! Good day :)

Comment: I'm glad it help :)